# Show covers in Xbox Music for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, music, xbox-music

Is it possible to tell the app to show covers named "cover.jpg" or "folder.jpg" if they exist in the same folder as an Mp3 it is playing?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, at least not that I've found.

As far as I've been able to deduce, they need to either be embedded in the music file (MP3), or available via the Internet (you may have to enable that preference).

Here's another thread (from TheGreenButton) talking about the same thing, with the same conclusion: [XBOX Music - My Music no cover images?](http://www.thegreenbutton.tv/forums/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=3407)